# installed a new raw drive in my asus g74sx and cant seem to get my win7 disk to boot.

Tags: windows-7, asus-laptop

After installing my new sata hdd my asus g74sx just shows a    j_    with the underscore flashing of course on the screen.   Please help.

Comment: Have you verified the boot order of the drives?  If this new drive is supose to have an OS on it, have you installed it, sounds like you have not.

Comment: The new drive is a raw drive. I installed it. Turned on system, placed the windows install disk. Rebooted the system. The POST screen came on showing the asus logo, and then it goes blank showing a lower case j with a blinking underscore. I then rebooted, Entered the bios and verified that it was booting from disc. Only to recieve the same result.

Comment: That laptop has space for 2 HDDs/SSDs. Did you remove the one that was in there already or leave it in? Also, if you have the windows image on a thumbdrive, it may work better. The default disk drive that comes with the g74sx was always shotty ( mine, at least.)

Comment: The slave drive was removed and never replaced. and the master (with win7 opsys) went bad, so i replaced the only one that was there. I do have a spare drive , unfortunately at this point i dont have a connecting cord to install it in the laptop. Could anyone explain the 'j' code?

Comment: Also, the usb failed also.

Comment: So you have changed the boot order, you never answered this question, it should be answered

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't answer directly to the question regarding the "j_".

But, I see some confusion in here. So, understand you have a new raw SATA disk seated in, and aim to install Windows 7? into it, probably from an installation DVD, or maybe from an installation USB stick. Anyway the DVD should be readily bootable, if in good condition and correctly defined in BIOS, but the USB is more tricky with exact bootable requirements/contents and also correctly defined in BIOS. Some more info on the BIOS type may help someone to give a better answer.

Comment: I have tried to reinstall using windows 7 (oem) install. I then tried windows 7 fire edition( which was recently loaded onto the tower i am using now.) I then used hirens boot cd to repartition the drive hoping that would help. Honestly at this point I believe the disc are not bootable for some reason. The hirens boot disk worked fine, and why the oem windows disc wont boot is confusing. The fire edition disc I know is bootable as i just used it on a netbook, of all things. Worked fine. I did alleviate the 'j-' to replace it with ' NTLDR is missing' code...

Comment: Please, still some more accuracy with the wording, use DVD, CD, HDD instead of plain install or disc or other words to be understood right ... Anyway, quite hard to advice not seeing all the even invisible behaviour going on on these trials.

Comment: I am sorry for the lack of information. I will begin with today.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Your model seems to point to [this laptop](https://www.asus.com/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-G74SX/).  That is a modern system, as such it uses UEFI firmware rather than BIOS firmware. That requires a different answer compared to BIOS & bootproblems answers.

```
  The slave drive was removed and never replaced.
```

Slave drive? It is a SATA system, which does not have single.master/slave settings. Those were used with PATA. Each SATA drive in a laptop works on its own.

```
the master (with win7 went bad, so I replaced the only one that was there.
```

OK, so your HDD went bad and was replaced. No old settings kept.

```
I have tried to reinstall using windows 7
```

OK. You are using windows 7. Windows 7 is not fully EFI prepared. You can either:

- Go to the firmware (UEFI) and enable CMS. Those are compatability shims which enable backward compatability. With CSM on and secure boot off you should be able to boot from a Windows 7 DVD or a classic windows 7 install USB pendrive.
  (You can -and should- also verify that these media work on other machines. No reinstall needed, just validate that you can boot from them).
- Alternative, you can keep the firmware in the normal EFI mode and boot from the windows 7 DVD. That one is sort of EFI prepared.
- Alternatively, you can use normal EFI mode and prepare an windows install USB pendrive. WIndows was not fully ready and this requires moving some files around on the pendrive. It also needs a FAT32 formatted drive (not NTFS) and any bootsectors are ignored.

  Could anyone explain the 'j' code?

If it is not in the manual, then sadly no.

Can you enter the firmware and see which boot options are defined? EFI does store some information which may point to the old disk. Can you make sure that it is clean?